# Nextcloud vs FTP/Samba on local network

Tags: networking, ftp, raspberry-pi, samba

I'm using a `raspberry pi` with attached HDD and `Nextcloud` installed as a local network storage now.
I'm also using `Open-VPN` to access local `Nextcloud` files from outside sometimes.
I have problems with stability of the `Nextcloud` when I'm uploading a lot of files at once or a large sized files (network lockdowns, errors etc).
Also the `Raspberry` is already running for a couple of years and will probably break sometimes. After the breaking I was thinking it will be very complicated to access files on HDD formatted for the `Raspberry` and also locked for root user. I have a one TP-Link router which is not in use right now and has a FTP/Samba function to access HDD files. I'm thinking about going for it.
There would be also a merit of using the router as access-point (wifi extender).
But I'm still not decided for it. At least it will take more electricity.
Could someone please suggest me pros/consts to consider during the decision?

Comment: Its difficult to understand exactly what you are asking.  Nextcloud, FTP and SAMBA are all optimised for different tasks, so you may want to elaborate more exactly on your usage case.   Accessing files on HDD from a Pi should not be difficult if you have access to a system running Linux and root access. It looks like Nexcloud stores files in a very easy-to-access way (ie presents as a standard filesystem).  Were it me, I'd be fixing the network issues related to Nextcloud - most likely you need QoS and to limit the throughput to less then the speed of your network connection

Comment: FTP is a horrible protocol - I would not seriously consider it.  SAMBA is better, but not designed for syncing across devices - and if you do go the TPLink route, make sure you can put it behind a VPN. I'm very happy with my Nextcloud box in a datacenter, and just syncing to my devices wherever they are.  Of-course, I do have access to effectively free compute in a DC.  Not sure your budget or storage needs.